# Tabs within a content type

Tags: routes

I have a question about tabs. I'm using a content type hotel with all the information about a hotel for example, hotel residence, location, food, spa, sports ... At this moment this is just one big list of text. I was trying to make tabs for it because this is I think the solution. I was trying it with the module quick tabs but there I have to use nodes or views to make the tabs so i don't know what to do know because it's impossible to put every element (location, food,...) from every hotel (40) in a view. 
Do you guys have any ideas?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you want to use the [Field Group](http://drupal.org/project/field_group) module.

This module allows you to group a number of fields on a content type together. You can then choose from a number of different display options for that group, including tabs.

Answer (score 1):

I needed something similar for an estate agent style site and made [Build mode tabs](http://drupal.org/project/bmtabs) to allow you to use custom build modes (view modes in D7) as custom tabs. This worked well for me because I wanted some of the same fields shown on different tabs. It's only D6 but I'd be happy to port it if there was interest.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are trying to do ... views can certainly handle all the hotels etc.  To do so:

1. Create taxonomy vocabularies that cover each category of information you want, such as location, food, amenities etc.
2. Create a new article content type with fields (requires Chaos Tools enabled) attached to each vocabulary.  This permits you to create tags for each category stored in a field of the content type.
3. Create a view definition and configure a view page in it to filter on specific fields.  Give it a path name such as `hotel/%/general` Set the menu type to default tabs (parent exists) and give the tab a name.  THe % is a wildcard and is used for contextual filtering.  This allows dynamic responses by views to the URL name you place in the % position.
4. Create another view page in the same view definition and configure its filters differently. Give it a path such as `hotel/%/<a different category>` and define its menu as menu tab (parent exists).

If properly configured, you would have a view that responds to `hotel/%` and displays the default filtered pages and two tabs, one for a default and the other for your other tab.  IF you are new to DRupal, some of this may not make sense.  I suggest you watch the video series "Taming the Beast"at nodeone.se to get a handle on what views does and then come back to Drupal.stackexchange, I am sure there will be more questions :)

Comment: if i understand everything well. I have to create a new CT with taxonomy linked to the fields (taxonomy (location) = field(location) When i'm setting up my view i can add the taxonomy into my filter (=to only display that field) 
At this moment I have for example hotel1/facilities, hotel2/facilities, hotel3/facilities... With the % wildcard the view can be used as for example %/facilities, %/wildcard, ... .am I right

Comment: I believe the path cannot start with %, so you would need paths such as hotels/%/facilities.

Comment: hotels/hotel1 would be an actual article page that contains information on hotel1. Setting a field with terms such as location, amenities, etc. creates a flag for the article and view pages (in a view definition) that can be set to filter for articles with that flag. You would then create a contextual filter to see which hotel is in the URL % position and the view will only show the specified hotels amenitities or location info article.

Comment: I am concerned that this may be a bit confusing if your not familiar with views.  Watch the videos and it will be a lot clearer.

Comment: On this site, if you think an answer is good, give it an up arrow.  If you accept it as the correct answer, give it a check mark.

Comment: Hello @JoeS. I was trying to fix the problem with your solution but I wasn't able to do it. I have figured out another solution. I made a block from 2 elements with the CCK module and afterwards I used the blocks to show in the quick tab module.